# How to Make Text Stay Inside Div?

Tags: html, css, text

[On this site,](http://dogsitterlondon.com) this text "Dog sitting allows your dog to stay at home in a relaxed and familiar environment while you're away." is supposed to be higher, next to the photo.

Any idea how to get the text to be up next to the image where it's supposed to be?

CSS:

```
#top    {
    height:400px;
    width:1024px;
}
#textright  {
    float:right;
    clear:both;
    width:300px;
}
```

Thank you,

Tara

Comment: give a width property to your #top div

Comment: It looks alright in Firefox 4, what browser do you use?

Comment: @calle I'm using Chrome @ibu Nope, that didn't make a difference - but thanks

Comment: I was using Firebug in Firefox 4 and it looks like the description is still in #top. However, it looks like your #list-nav is hidden. I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: @bryce Sorry, I don't know why that would be...? It's pretty basic HTML & CSS.

Comment: Sorry, I found your list-nav. Firebug was just doing something stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the 16px margin as follows:

```
div#textright>p:first-child
{
margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Cannot load you page in any browser except IE9!

Comment: I can load it in Safari and Chrome

Comment: just remove clear: both from #textright. By the way your site is changing a lot and it is very difficult to troubleshoot it when the code changes.

Answer (score 1):

Add `float:left` to the dog image

and add `clear:both;` to `ul#list-nav`

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because it's floating, and the dog picture doesn't leave any room for it.

If you add `float:left` to the dog picture, remove the `width:390px;` from #textright, and add `clear:both` or `float:left` to the UL, it works nice.

Comment: This made the Navi better but still didn't put the text in the same place - Thanks though